# Proxy requests from NGINX to Cloudfront system stop working when using a variable in proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

We are proxying requests to a AWS cloudfront server in NGINX like this:

```
location /assets/ {
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        Host    upstream.example.com;
    proxy_pass      https://upstream.example.com/assets/;
    proxy_set_header        Authorization "Basic Zm9vOmJhcg==";
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
}
```

As you can see, the cloudfront site needs a basic auth authorization.
We notices, that this caches the DNS entries of `upstream.example.com` and changed use now variables which cause a re-resolve. The re-resolve works fine.

```
resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;

location /assets/ {
    set $backend_website upstream.example.com;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        Host    upstream.example.com;
    proxy_pass      https://$backend_website/assets/;
    proxy_set_header        Authorization "Basic Zm9vOmJhcg==";
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
}
```

But now the actual requests do not work properly any more:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>***redacted***</RequestId>
<HostId>***redacted***</HostId>
</Error>
```

I assume that NGINX must make different requests now. But there seem only complex ways involving NJS/Lua to log the full requests.

Does anybody have a hint what's going on there? How can this be debugged?

EDIT: I added `proxy_cache off` to both, the old and the new configuration to make sure that the working asset is not cached -> but the result is the same, with the new config it does not work.

EDIT2:

I am trying this approach to log headers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55689741/288568

But it seems to log the incoming headers, not the headers I am setting via proxy_set_header

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a duplicate of question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230270/nginx-using-variable-in-proxy-pass-breaks-routing

My guess is that it's sending `https://upstream.example.com/assets/assets/`.

When variabilizing, try and set proxy_pass to `https://$backend_website$request_uri;`

Comment: yes, seems to be the same problem. I believe it cannot use `$request_uri` because the concatenation caused problems with Chinese letters in the URL in the past.
Anyways, I realized that I was able to simplify my proxy configuration (by matching location `/.*` and not location `/assets`) so that this problem does not apply anymore.